# Pipe stdout to obexftp bluetooth transfer?

Tags: pipe, bluetooth, stdout, file-transfer

Here I have command to transfer inputFile.tar to another bluetooth device (10:68:3F:57:7D:B6).

```
obexftp -b 10:68:3F:57:7D:B6 -p inputFile.tar
```

However, is it possible to use stdout as input for obexftp?

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
cat inputFile.tar | obexftp -b 10:68:3F:57:7D:B6 ...
gzip -fc inputFile.tar | obexftp -b 10:68:3F:57:7D:B6 ...
```

How can I do this? How do I tell obexftp to use stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a way with the pipe but you can try this:

obexftp -b 10:68:3F:57:7D:B6 - p $(cat inputFile.tar)

Return the sdout of the command in the $( )